# assign currency in invoice using quickbook online api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am creating `rails app which are integrate with Quick book account`.

My problem is when i am create invoice that same invoice need to create in `quick book account` but how to pass `currency` for quick book using API.

I tried to found solutions but not success yet.

Any one have a idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Invoice entity doc - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice

Invoice entity has an attribute with name CurrencyRef ( DataType - [CurrencyRef](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics#CurrencyRefType)).

Ex -

```
<Invoice>
     ...
     <CurrencyRef name="Canadian Dollar">CAD</CurrencyRef>
    ...
 </Invoice>
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, your are right "CurrencyRef" is invoice attribute but how to add it in invoice api. This is only when get invoice but at create time how to integrate it?

Comment: If you try to create an Invoice using any RestClient, then you need to add in the payload and if you use IPP's devkit then you need to use the corresponding setter method of this attribute.

Comment: I am using "Quickbooks-Ruby" gem for rails application to integrate Quickbooks

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mentioned you are using the [quickbooks-ruby](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) gem.

I recently added this feature to the gem for invoices via this [PR](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/commit/a57a0691672d2ae95af12602959ce5dcf6821c7e).

In short do this:

```
invoice = Quickbooks::Model::Invoice.new
invoice.currency_id = 'CAD'
invoice.currency_ref.name = 'Canadian Dollar'
```